# How to use .html() in IE8 and jquery ? without flickering the html page?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8

jquery + html + Rails 4

```
$('#onward').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'bus_listing', :is_return => true) %>"); // not working in < IE8. Other browser working fine
```

bus_listing is a partial.

```
$('#onward')[0].innerHTML = "<%= escape_javascript(render 'bus_listing', :is_return => false) %>"; // working in but full Html page is flickering and not adding the new data in html.
```

Any solution for .html() replacement in IE8. please share.

Comment: Try giving it like this `$('#onward').append("<%= j render(:partial => 'bus_listing',:is_return => true) %>");`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try innerHTML ?

```
document.getElementById('onward').innerHTML="<%= escape_javascript(render 'bus_listing', :is_return => true) %>"
```

Comment: Yes its working but i am using .multiselect on select tag that is going off. i mean <select><option></option></select> tag styles or js is not working

Comment: $("#"+ prefix + "schedule_id").multiselect({
      header: 'Travels',
      noneSelectedText: 'Travels',
      selectedText: 'Travels',
      prefix: prefix + 'travels',
    }).select2;

Comment: and where to use innerHTML?

Comment: @C this <script> is inside the html only.